# Whether convolution followed by down sampling equals wavelet decomposition

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, filter-design, wavelet

[image]I know that wavelet decomposition equals convolution followed by down sampling by two.I tried to test this on mat lab on haar wavelet. I write the below code and compared with the default wavedec command in mat lab. The code I wrote is shown below.

```
clear all
clc
h=[0.7071    0.7071];% Haar scaling filter
g=[-0.7071    0.7071];%Haar wavelet filter
x=[1:10];% Input 
h=fliplr(h);% h(-m)
g=fliplr(g);%g(-m)
s=conv(h,x);
s=downsample(s,2)
d=conv(g,x);
d=downsample(d,2)
[a L]=wavedec(x,1,'haar') % for comparison
```

After running this program I get `s =  0.7071    3.5355    6.3639    9.1923   12.0207    7.0710.
d =  0.7071    0.7071    0.7071    0.7071    0.7071   -7.0710  and the wavedec out put as a = 2.1213    4.9497    7.7782   10.6066   13.4350   -0.7071   -0.7071   -0.7071   -0.7071   -0.7071. L =   5     5    10`

I dont know why wavedec and my code gives different out puts, will any one help???

Comment: where did you read that, in which context?

Comment: In every context filtering corresponds to convolution.

Comment: true, but still, this is definitely (and trivially to counter-prove by convolving with $\delta(t)$) not the case for every filter. and hence, you're missing an important part of the original description. And hence, I ask for context.

Comment: In case of Discrete wavelet transform, high pass and low pass coefficients at each level are obtained with the convolution of the corresponding filter coefficients followed by down sampling.. for details please go to matlab website ,(following link and go to more about section) http://in.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wavedec.html

Comment: http://in.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wavedec.html

Comment: @MarcusMüller  I had attached a screen shot from mathworks, mathworks itself says that coefficients are obtained by the convolution of corresponding vectors in wavedec, please see

Comment: Your question has beeen answered. Do not hesitate to vote for the useful ones and accept the most suitable

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, no!

> I know that wavelet decomposition equals convolution followed by down sampling by two

No again. Some linear wavelet decompositions can be turned into a cascade of convolutions followed by downsampling. But wavelets are much more general. Their discrete implementations involve intricate properties in filters, downsampling, and levels.

If you just filter a signal  by some filter, and downsample, in general, you get almost nothing but aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it, downsample  command in matlab takes first element then 3rd,5th etc where downsampling in wavedec starts from 2,4,6...more over fliping of wavelet filters are not required ..Instead of using downsample command we can repalce with `s=s(2:2:length(s))`

Comment: Classical, for each level of DWT, you have two options: delete every odd or every even sample